# Copy constructor for c++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

**I have the following c++ code:**

```
    class test1{};      
    class test2{ test2();};
    class test3{ test3(int); };

    test1 t1(test1());  //compile ok
    test1 t2(test2());  //compile ok
    test1 t3(test3(int())); //compile ok
    test1 t4(test3(10));    
    //compile error: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'test3' to 'const test1&'
```

why?

Comment: You didn't create a constructor for test1 that takes a test3 object as a parameter. What did you expect? (If you're referring to `test1 t2(test2());` this is most likely MVP)

Comment: it's reasonable that t4 can not be constructed,but why can t3 be constructed? is there any difference between t3 and t4?

Comment: Yes there is a difference t2 and t3 are a function declaration, not a variable definition, t1 too by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say that compiles okay does not actually do what you want, it declares a function, it does not define a variable. This is the "Most Vexing Parse" or MVP that Borgleader refers to.

Try to compile with the following, which is actually what you mean and you will see that it fails:

```
test1 t2( (test2()) );
```

You need to define these copy constructors to use them. test2 does not derive from test1 so it cannot use inheritance and there is no magical type conversion that fixes it for you.

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks for the edit, I just noticed it myself when the edit notification came up ;)